# Goldhaber experiment - Why are there only left-handed neutrinos?

Tags: particle-physics, neutrinos, chirality, helicity

> "From the [Goldhaber experiment](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldhaber-Experiment) we can deduce that there are **only** left handed neutrinos."

I don't understand this. Can't we find an experiment that only produces overwhelmingly right handed neutrinos?

Comment: Related: [Experiments to find right handed neutrinos](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/410619/)

Comment: You don't provide your source and specify the "we".  Who is it that "knows" that? You don't want to meet them, do you?

Comment: Review your [sterile neutrinos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sterile_neutrino).  The Goldhaber experiment has nothing to say about them.

Answer (score 1):

**No.**

The Goldhaber experiment's purpose was to test the masslessness hypothesis of neutrinos, which was proposed in 1957 by Lev Landau and Abdus Salam. The motivation for this hypothesis was that this was the simplest possible parity-violating theory for weak interactions. In it, neutrino is strictly a left-handed particle. In a parity-conserving theory one should see an equal amount of left- and right-handed neutrinos. No right-handed were seen.

The particle theorists speculate that there are *sterile* neutrinos, that is, neutrinos with no weak interactions, only gravity. These would be right-handed neutrinos, but their existence is as of today not proven.